# Change Cell Range Value to Contents of Double Clicked Cell By Relative Location

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the values of a range of cells (Drop-Down List) to the contents of a double clicked cell which say either PASS, FAIL, or just a dash (   -  ).

I am able to get this working when I specify the exact range of the Drop-down List cells, but because I would like to use this same feature multiple times down through the spreadsheet, I'd like to be able to change the drop-downs relative to the double clicked cell's location, not a specific set of cells.

This is my code currently. Any pointers in the right direction would be so helpful!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    On Error GoTo M
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V:V,W:W,X:X")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
        Range("E33:T33").Value = Target.Value
    End If
    Exit Sub
M:
    MsgBox "Error"
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = True
    On Error GoTo M
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("V:X")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
        Target.EntireRow.Cells(5).Resize(1, 16).Value = Target.Value
    End If
    Exit Sub
    M:
    MsgBox "Error"

End Sub
```